# Getting "Thread 1 fatal error index out of range"

Tags: swift5, xcode11

I am getting the following error "thread 1 fatal error index out of range", which is appearing in my feedViewController and AppDelegate

What could be the cause of this? I am very new to coding and mainly following tutorials, however this error has not been covered.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var userEmailArray = [String]()
var userCommentArray = [String]()
var likeArray = [Int]()
var userImageArray = [String]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    getDataFromFirestore()
}

func getDataFromFirestore() {
    
    let fireStoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
    
   /* let settings = fireStoreDatabase.settings
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    fireStoreDatabase.settings = settings
*/
     fireStoreDatabase.collection("Posts").order(by: "date", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    if snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil {
                        
                        self.userImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.userEmailArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.userCommentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.likeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                      
                        
                        
                        for document in snapshot!.documents {
                            let documentID = document.documentID
                            
                            if let postedBy = document.get("postedBy") as? String {
                                self.userEmailArray.append(postedBy)
                            }
                            
                            if let postComment = document.get("postComment") as? String {
                                self.userCommentArray.append(postComment)
                            }
                            
                            if let likes = document.get("likes") as? Int {
                                self.likeArray.append(likes)
                            }
                            
                            if let imageUrl = document.get("imageUrl") as? String {
                                self.userImageArray.append(imageUrl)
                            }
                            
                            
                        }
                        
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return userEmailArray.count
        }
     
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
            cell.userEmailLabel.text = userEmailArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.likeLabel.text = String(likeArray[indexPath.row])
            cell.commentLabel.text = userCommentArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.userImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userImageArray[indexPath.row]))

            return cell
        }



    }
```

This is the line where the error is:

```
            cell.userImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userImageArray[indexPath.row]))
```

Comment: Your 4 arrays should have the same length. Use the debugger to check if this is true.